# Is there a way to create dynamic parameter?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I have filter for my dataset:

Keep rows where date is on or after $filter_date

Can I set parameter $filter_date to be 60 days (or 8 weeks or 2 months) away from today?

Comment: While Andrew's approach is comprehensive, there is also in-progress feature development work in Contour to support relative date parameters in both the Reports and Contour interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

You can use an expression paired with a dynamic parameter as such:

```
date_diff(current_date(), date1) <= $number_of_days
```

[image]

You can read more on the date/time functions here:
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/contour/expressions-relative-dates/#deriving-relative-dates

Comment: thank You for answer. use of parameters is more desired from end-user side, as it gives better UX. 
'date_diff(current_date(), date1) <= $number_of_days' ?
can you double-check the link You provided, as it gives error "this site can't be reached".

Comment: Hi Jonas, yes that should work. Sorry I didn't understand the question well.  For the link, you need to replace https://developers.palantirfoundry.com with the link to your Foundry instance.